# New Kinect One Permssion issues

Tags: ros, iai-kinect2, root, permission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Folks,

I am using the Kinect One, but I am having permissions issues.
I'm using this rospackage:

```
https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2
```

I followed every instruction given in the README files in order to install the drivers, but I can't run the roslaunch without first running the following command from the "libfreenect" folder:

```
sudo .~/libfreenect2/examples/protonect/bin/Protonect
```

After I do that and close the program, then I can lunch my Kinect rospackage (Protonect is the executable example project that comes with libfreenect).

I did the udev rules and all that already, and I installed/re-installed it in three different machines, and I still have the same problem in all three.

Is there a way to give the Protonect executable root permission/access so that "sudo" is never again needed? Would that solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203050/new-kinect-one-permssion-issues/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried adding a line specific to your ProductID to your 90-kinect2.rules?
from the ReadMe:
Check if the idProduct of your sensor is in the list. If not just add another line with the idProduct of your sensor. You can obtain it by running dmesg | grep "045e". Reconnect the sensor and you should be able to access it.

---

Originally posted by [TedK](https://answers.ros.org/users/21322/tedk/) with karma: 16 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-02-12**:
See my output below (which is similar what's already on the README file example)

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-02-12**:
USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d9
USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d9
USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d8
USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d9
USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d9
USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d8